# Create a link between two objects

Tags: php, class, oop

The question may be a bit unclear, however, I'll try to explain what I mean. In modern programming, every thing must be an object! For example: Just suppose that I have an object called "Language", and of course every language consists of many phrases, so I have another object called "Phrase", Now, how can I create a link between this "Language" object, and the "Phrase", Just like I say "The x phrase is a part of the y language, and the y language contain that x phrase.", how can I say that programmatically, how can I say that in php for example?

I hope that you understand what I mean.

Comment: Your language object will have either a constructor or a custom method that creates phrases for that language, probably saving each instance to a property of the language object: each time `$this->phrases[] = new Phrase();`. Then you'll have a method within the language object that will "get me all phrases for a language" - simply returning the property (array) containing all the phrases, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, a little to late. @Robin provided a good answer. Anyways, I included how to use it as well.

```
class Language {
    private $phrases = array();

    public function addPhrase(Phrase $phrase) {
        $this->phrases[] = $phrase;
    }

    public function getPhrases() {
        return $this->phrases;
    }
}

class Phrase {
    private $value = null;

    function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function Value() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$language = new Language();
$language->addPhrase(new Phrase("phrase1"));
$language->addPhrase(new Phrase("phrase2"));

foreach($language->getPhrases() as $phrase)
    printf("%s\n", $phrase->Value());
```

Comment: Neither you or @Robin have answered the part of the question relating to how to get Languages that a Phrase belongs to

Comment: Thank you. But, I have a small question, can I add a key to the phrase to get it easily, for example: `$language->getPhrase('welcome_phrase');` and that get the Phrase class that have the welcome phrase ?

Comment: To add a key, you have to specify one when in the addPhrase method, like ``$this->phrases['welcome_phrase'] = $phrase``. Also the method itself must have another argument as the $key. Then you must create a ``getPhrase($key)`` method which gets the phrase by the key specified.

Comment: and can I get the language that the phrase belongs to? Just like that: `(new Phrase("Phrase1"))->getLanguage();`

Comment: You cannot do it directly like that, when you create a Phrase object you have not specified a linked Language object to it. One way is to link them when you add the phrase to the language, in the addPhrase method you do ``$this->phrase->setLanguage($this)`` but you have to implement ``setLanguage`` method in your Phrase class, also add a getLanguage method as well to get it back or null if it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about using objects, the best way to start is by creating classes. In your case, you should create both a `Language` and a `Phrase` class. See the example code below:

**Language.class.php**

```
<?php

class Language {

  private $phrases = array();

  public function phrases() {
   return $this->phrases;
  }

  public function addPhrase(Phrase $phrase) {
   array_push($this->phrases, $phrase);
  }

  public function getPhraseByIndex($index) {
   if(!is_null($this->phrases[$index]))
    return $this->phrases[$index];
   else
    return null;
  }

  public function removePhraseByIndex($index) {
   unset($this->phrases[$index]);
   array_values($this->phrases);
  }

}
?>
```

**Phrase.class.php**

```
<?php

class Phrase {

  private $text;

  public function __construct($text) {
    $this->update($text);
  }

  public function update($text) {
   $this->text = $text;
  }

  public function getText() {
   return $this->text;
  }

}
?>
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you :D, a good answer, but not exactly what I need, but thank you anyway.

Comment: You're welcome! The example above is a pretty standard way to work with entities, so I hope you can use the structure for future purposes ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is called Dependency Injection, meaning you have to inject the object if another depends on it.

There are 3 ways of injections: constructor, method and property injection.

@msfoster already showed you how to inject via method, which is what you need in your case.

For the other 2 ways see [dependency injection in php](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-in-php--net-28146)

Comment: Thank you! but I know Dependency Injection, but I can't do what I want just with it! I think there is something else I must do

Comment: DI will work for you, just that you need a little bit more work than most examples out there.

Answer (score -1):

PHP with objects. The best I could do with the current explanation.

`$english = (object) array('phrases' => array ('1' => 'Phrase one here', '2' => 'Phrase two here', '3' => 'Phrase three here'));`

or for both of them to be objects

```
$english_phrases = array('Phrase one here', 'Phrase two here', 'Phrase three here');
$english = array('phrases' => $phrases);
```